# Setting SAAS variables in IONIC 6

Tags: ionic-framework, saas

I have an ionic v6 application. i have setup my global saas variables.  The saas variables work fine with normal css elements, but do not seem to work with Ionic variables.

```
//.scss file
@import "./variables";
#page{
   .tube-button {
    --background: $red_color;
     font-size: $font-size;
  }
 }

//html
 <IonButton className="tube-button">Quick Book</IonButton>
```

the **$red_color** saas variable that is defined in _variables.scss does not work with **--background** , hence I have to hard code the colour. This i have noticed is with all the ionic variables that i want to override in my components.

The 2nd line with **font-size** works with the saas variable **$font-size**

could anyone guide on how I can achieve this without having to hard code SAAS variables for all the ionic variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. This issue has nothing to do with IONIC. Its a SAAS behavior. It ignores attributes with --. hence in order for the transpiling to work with CSS variables with saas, the above code should change to

```
    --background: #{$red_color};
```